# Aspnetcore authentication Correlation failed

Tags: asp.net-core

I've searched through the different SO answers and on Aspnetcore Authentication on GIT but none of the solutions help. I have an issue with "correlation failed" and the reason is the correlation cookie is not being set even though it's clearly in the response header of the redirect to Google.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxqYb.png)

Here's the response in Fiddler:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=996823962179-1vvr5h2icjroveset9849e8aqdks1g66.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsignin-google&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=CfDJ8EGRdEf8M7VDtyNKY6R10TxxM2kHFoDlOBkCQKoMQJXX3QPKcyH8quz80oy8Wd7Rq1Nnb-KhklzrC-XK4WOhikAVtJuFHIk_M4ZvLY8Le2FkjVNxJrHDsZeg7o1sMrABd_md1jxi-LelhURiB54SUAHbaJciseDc5NP897CSsrtYoPt_IWyqNOdxCjPntxwHYUzO2ZxIcfSLaLGu8rWlfHTEqvj_N7KQ0k8HQ8VwPYDXjAMwjjsGRdxR6dOl-vNfzfOqX0wZelvVsX5UIfzMjlCJ20lQxLIhlkhkpne14EYYNkJufqF4ZADD13jvsj4qnw
>   Server: Kestrel
>   Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.Google.WKzW6di96f3Fbh4ThkfIFHteUvNLusesaT0VjAMhrDU=N; expires=Sat, 17 Nov 2018 16:14:20 GMT; path=/signin-google; secure; samesite=strict; httponly
>   Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=strict; httponly
>   Date: Fri, 28 Dec 2018 03:45:54 GMT
>   Content-Length: 0

I have the dataprotection set to store keys to one location and that is working as expected. My source control is here: 
https://github.com/jjkesinger/charts/tree/master/Charts

Any ideas? Does TLS on the local machine have anything to do with it? I can clone this project to another machine and it works fine. The machine it isn't working on is a Windows 10 dell experion

Comment: Also downloaded the sample https://github.com/aspnet/Security and get the correlation failed error. Same behavior- no correlation cookie is persisted even though the header in the 302 to google/fb/git etc says set-header

Comment: Have you tried to reset all your browser settings? (I mean the whole deal). And/or try a different browser. It is very easy to inadvertently change some settings that may cause this. I had a similar situation recently (chrome stuck in infinite loop after I enabled https support for localhost development), and resetting browser settings (ALL of it, except the history cache; and for ALL past time) "fixed" it.

Comment: Ended up being my cookie policy was set to strict. Changed to lax and it works.

Comment: Yeah, samesite=strict is not compatible with OAuth.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue as well and had to set the the following options:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(g => 
{
   g.ClientId = XXXXXXX;
   g.ClientSecret = XXXXXX;
   g.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
}
```

The last line is what fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

SamesiteMode.Lax does not login you immediately

You need to use this code :

```
    .AddGoogle(o =>
    {
        o.ClientId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
        o.ClientSecret = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");
        o.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        o.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    })
```

and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting this issue for over a week and finally got the solution from Tanver on the Auth0 help desk.  SameSite.None requires you to [run your web server (even localhost) via https](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos).  Fixed my problem!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Although in your case the real problem was that you had a cookie policy of `samesite=strict`, what this error *normally* means is that the `REDIRECT_URI` defined in the app registration at the identity provider does not correlate with (does not match) the value supplied in `options.CallbackPath`.

I think they say "correlate" rather than "match" because it doesn't have to be the same string. In the sample below I supply only `/signin-microsoft` because this correlates to both `http://localhost:5000/signin-microsoft` and `https://production-domain-name/app-path.../signin-microsoft` both of which are define in the app registration on Azure.

```
.AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
    // SET THIS TO CORRELATE WITH REDIRECT_URI THAT YOU  
    // DEFINED IN THE APP REGISTRATION AT THE APP PROVIDER
    microsoftOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-microsoft"; 
})
```

Despite being technically reasonable, this is a very unhelpful exception message. There's no reason they couldn't have said `WRONG CALLBACK PATH Provider did not call back on the path specified in options.CallbackPath Ensure REDIRECT_URI in app registration at provider correlates to the value supplied in options.CallbackPath`

None of the samples specify a callback path so chances are high that many people will not supply one at all (also leading to this problem).